# How to run several transactions locally on geth?

Tags: go-ethereum

How can I run several arbitrary transactions on top of each other locally?

I am looking for something like [debug_traceTransaction](https://geth.ethereum.org/docs/rpc/ns-debug#debug_tracetransaction), and I was wondering if there was a similar feature in Geth with all transactions taken as input?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I could not find any functions that does this and implemented this feature by forking the Ethereum mainnet and running transactions on local computer with the help of hardhat. You can find the [Github Repository](https://github.com/Allarious/MEVoila) here. The function for running transactions in order is sendRawTransactions.